# Firebase Firestore Timestamp to Date Issue

Tags: swift, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

After upgrading my code to Swift 5, Firestore is returning `NSDate` as `FIRTimestamp`. When I am trying to receive it as `Date` it throwing error as:

> Could not cast value of type 'FIRTimestamp' (0x107aab8c0) to 'NSNumber' (0x10b8fbe00).

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 7):

Here is the code which is used to get Timestamp value from Firestore and convert it into `NSDate`

```
let timestamp: Timestamp = (filteredtotalArray[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "requestedDate")! as! Timestamp
let RequestedDate = timestamp.dateValue()
```

Comment: Really, its just the second line.